Does quantum cosmology show that the universe can just come out of nothing?
I am struggling with my faith a lot and yesterday I was taking to my Atheist friend and when we were talking about the origin of the universe, he suggested that quantum cosmology could be the origin of the universe, is this true and does this mean that we no longer have a need for God?

I don't believe the bible or Christian sects necessarily say how God created the universe, just that he did. If you are struggling with faith talking to a local church leader will probably provide more comfort and specific guidance than strangers on the internet

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

Most of us don't really have any real idea what quantum cosmology is all about. Nor do the physicists, actually. Even Einstein was humble enough to admit that, after a lifetime pondering them, he still had not one single clue what an electron really was. These things are beyond us. But faith in God is not beyond us. His Creation, all around us, above us and beneath our feet, cries out, in a multitude of ways, that God is.

I certainly wouldn't mind talking about this, but not as a Q&A topic on the site.

It's very possible that Quantum Cosmology actually requires God.  https://www.nature.com/articles/d41586-023-04024-z

It's also possible QC is full of excrement. Materialists have a serious dedication to trying to explain what they see without resort to God, and many of those explanations are... problematic. Meanwhile, many Scripture-believing scientists believe that Genesis 1 is an accurate history of Creation and that Earth is ~6,000 years old. Even if not (despite much evidence that is is), the idea that life got where it is without "help" is incredibly unlikely. So, no, we absolutely (still) need God.

Science as a science is different from science as a religion. Science is unable to determine how things came into being, this is a matter of a belief system.
Look at any landscape, sky, mountain or ocean panorama and you will see the beauty, power and glory of God in his creation. It is declared by God not a human theory.
To believe something as ridiculous as a scientific theory to explain all that which is glorious and unexplainable by men, well, is simply foolish and irrational. It is made to appear smart only because a few mathematical formulas embellish the weak beliefs presumed (without proof).
I would pay no attention to science as a religion. Keep science as a science. That’s its natural place and its God-given purpose for us to use.
Psalms 19:1-4:

The heavens declare the glory of God;
the skies proclaim the work of his hands.
Day after day they pour forth speech;
night after night they reveal knowledge.
They have no speech, they use no words;
no sound is heard from them.
Yet their voice goes out into all the earth,
their words to the ends of the world.
In the heavens God has pitched a tent for the sun.

To explain a little more deeply about the difference between science and religion:
Science is not even working with a full set of logic when it theorizes metaphysical ideas (science as a religion).  In fact, by making that specific claim the person moves science into the metaphysical, something beyond the realm of the observable and the repeatable where there is no physical reality, but science arrogantly pretends to understand it. This is the  epitome of what science is not. This is science as a religion, which is not that different from astrology. What makes science a science, as opposed to the discipline of logic, philosophy or religion, is that it narrows the scope of allowed thinking with the premise that only the material world exists. All premises of every argument must start with an observation of the physical and then try to explain how one material manifestation is related to another.
This narrow scope of science limits its ability to argue with logic that have different premises or beliefs. At least you must abandon science and enter the foolish realm of philosophy to do that.
Most humans always have and probably always will start with the belief that there is a God and that the physical is not all there is.  Science can’t even figure that basic human experience out because in deed it appears to be a law of nature just as evil is also an experience of another law of nature. And so also the recognition of God manifesting his glory in nature is a true law.
